Widget's button is not clickable
My application is in UIKit.
I am developing a medium-sized widget for my application. The widget has been created using SwiftUI.  The widget contains three buttons, each intended to navigate the user to a specific screen within the app.
Currently, the design of my widget looks good, and it appears correctly on the home screen. However, when I tap on any of the three buttons, the button click event does not seem to be working.
When I tap on a button, the entire widget is clicked. However, I want to distinguish and manage the click events for each of the three buttons individually.
I have already referred to this but that's not working
Here is my code:
struct appWidgetEntryView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily

    var body: some View {
        Group {
          if widgetFamily == .systemMedium {
                RectangleWidgetView() //This is medium widget view 
            }
        }
    }
}
struct RectangleWidgetView: View {
            
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack(spacing: 8){
          //button 1 (View contacts)
            Button(action: {
                // Action
                print("****View Contacts Clicked*****")
                
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("View Contacts")
                        .font(.system(size: buttonFontSize))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .frame(height: buttonHeight)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                    
                    Image("contacts")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
          //button 2 (Add Contacts)
            Button(action: {
                UserDefaults(suiteName: WidgetKitManager.Name.appGroup.rawValue)?.setValue("AddContact", forKey: "widgetAction")
                
                print("****Add contact Clicked*****")
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Add Contact")
                        .font(.system(size: buttonFontSize))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .frame(height: buttonHeight)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                    
                    Image("float_add")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
          //button 3 (Delete Contact)
            Button(action: {
                UserDefaults(suiteName: WidgetKitManager.Name.appGroup.rawValue)?.setValue("deleteContact", forKey: "widgetAction")
                
                print("****Delete contact Clicked*****")
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Delete Contact")
                        .font(.system(size: buttonFontSize))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .frame(height: buttonHeight)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                    
                    Image("float_add")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(widgetBGColor)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .adoptableWidgetBackground(widgetBGColor) // Add this line
    }
}


Widget button click can be handled using AppIntent:
create a swift file ViewContactsAppIntent.swift
import Foundation
import AppIntents

struct ViewContactsAppIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "View Contacts Clicked"

    init(){}
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {

        print("Button Clicked*******: ")
        return .result()
    }
}

Use AppIntent like this:
Button(intent: ScanButtonIntent()) {
       HStack(spacing: 4) {
              Spacer()
              Text("View Contacts")
              .font(.system(size: buttonFontSize))
              .fontWeight(.medium)
              .foregroundStyle(.black)
              .frame(height: buttonHeight)
              .lineLimit(2)
                                        
             Image("contacts")
            .resizable()
             .scaledToFit()
             .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
             .foregroundStyle(.black)
              Spacer()
           }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)


The example code as given won't work for a couple of reasons. 1) The intent name does not match the example AppIntent class (ScanButtonIntent() ... should be ViewContactsAppIntent) and 2) this code assumes that there is an image named "contacts". Even so, I gave this answer a plus one because it did solve the issue for me by pointing out that I need to add intent: to the Button initializer (i.e. Button(intent: ScanButtonIntent()) even if it is misnamed in this example.

Noted, thanks...
